# Можно ли приложение, написанное на PyQt5 встроить в веб-страницу?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt

Хочу попробовать свое приложение, написанное на PyQt5, вставить на веб-страницу, можно ли такое осуществить?

P.S.: Кода не приложу, просто теоретический вопрос.

Comment: По состоянию на 2021 год - нельзя!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет. Но есть косвенный способ, который но очень затруднителен: переписать все классы  pyqt так, чтобы они возвращали html+js, полагаю этом метод нереализуем...
Так же есть вариант с выводом изображения программы в веб, мониторинг кликов при помощи js, затем передавать все нажатия в программу. Допустим при помощи pynput, и обновлять выведенное изображение яваскриптом, но это создаёт огромную дыру в безопасности...
Есть так же варианты с видео, но принципы теже что и с фото...

Comment: а как же QtWebEngine? Он является веб-сайтом и может содержать в себе веб.. а раз так, то с его помощью можно приложение на PyQt5 вклеить в веб-сайт